Grub is not working after CMOS reset
Issue:
My dual boot machine is directly booting into windows 11 without prompting grub. If I change the boot order and put the win 11 ssd behind the ubuntu I get that I have no bootable device selected.
Origin of the issue:
I have had a dual boot set up with win 11 on one SSD and on a second SSD I had Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted to renew my cooling paste and I think I accidentally have done a a CMOS rest. It prompted me after first boot, that CMOS reset has been done and all my settings are gone. (I thought no biggy).
I tried:

reordering boot order => either it boots into win11 or I get no boot device selected
Boot into Ubunutu on a usb and run boot-repair with recommended settings => no effect

I have attached pictures of boot order and the partitions of the SSDs. I think it is odd that on my Ubuntu SSD is a Microsoft partition. I thik this was not there before. But before I start to break more I am seeking help here.




After some digging I found a solution. It seems the issue can be rsolved by running:
In a windows terminal with admin permissions
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Source: Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help
If you also have this issue I recommend to also try the boot-repair tool or boot ordering, since both seemed to have helped people.
